# Is the rule of explosion (aka ex falso sequitur quodlibet) something that needs to be proved?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) and [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Explosion/Variant_2) pages, there are proofs presented for this rule, but what confuses me though is that I think we actually need to show that $\bot\vdash Q$ holds, not $(P\wedge\neg P)\vdash Q$ or $\vdash(P\wedge\neg P)\rightarrow Q$.
I know that $P\wedge\neg P$ is an obvious contradiction and in the natural deduction system I have seen you introduce a $\bot$ from $P$ and $\neg P$ on two separate lines, but still I don't think this necessarily means that $\bot$ is equivalent to $P\wedge\neg P$!

Comment: In Natural Deduction we have two basic possibilities: *(i)* $\bot$ as primitive, with the rule $\bot \vdash \varphi$ and $\lnot$ defiend. In this case, the intro- and elimination-rules for $\lnot$ are derived from those for $\to$ using the abbreviation: $\lnot P := P \to \bot$.

Comment: *(ii)* $\lnot$ as primitive with the "usual" intro- and elimination-rules.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So I guess in first case you don't need to derive this rule you just take it for accepted, and in the second one you don't even use $\bot$ symbol instead you use something like $P\wedge\neg P$ and those proofs are for this second case?

Comment: Correct; in the second case, the *Ex falso* "axiom" will be like: $\lnot A \to (A \to B)$.