# Is there a proof of LEM implying DNE that doesn't use $\bot\vdash\varphi$?

Tags: proof-writing, natural-deduction

Is there a proof not using $\bot\vdash\varphi$, proving that Law of The Excluded Middle implies Double Negation Elimination in natural deduction? The ones I've seen would use $\bot\vdash\varphi$ at some point.

Comment: At this point you should know the answer: It all depends on what proof system you are using.

Comment: @Bram28 Glad to see you here :D, would you plz answer these questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444337/is-this-a-proof-of-how-law-of-the-excluded-middle-implies-double-negation-elimin and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444424/is-rule-of-explosionex-falso-sequitur-quodlibet-something-that-needs-to-be-pro ?

Comment: For some systems, $\bot \rightarrow \phi$ is one of its defined rules.  For others, you can derive it from its rules. And for some, you can't, either because $\bot$ isn't part of its alphabet, or because the system is incomplete, or it is not a system for classical logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of thoughts:

First, any question like 'is there a proof ...' should always be couched relative to some proof system. i.e you should really ask 'Is there a proof system in which there exists a proof ...'

Second, when you ask for a proof that LEM implies DNE ... that's a little weird, since in classical logics DNE holds without making any further assumptions. That is, for all complete systems $S$ for classic propositional logic we have $\vdash_S \neg \neg \phi \rightarrow \phi$

EDIT: From the comments I understand you are looking for a proof that does not use LEM (nor $\bot \rightarrow \phi$ ... I'll refer to that rule as $\bot$ Elim) as one of its steps.  OK, below is a proof done in Fitch, where $\neg$ Elim is *defined* as going from $\neg \neg \phi$ to $\phi$, so that doesn't use LEM or $\bot$ Elim:

[image]

Finaly, if you're looking for a system where you do have to derive $\neg \neg \phi \rightarrow \phi$, but that still does not use LEM or $\bot$ Elim, I point you the [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system), which does not have LEM or $\bot$ Elim as its rules, but you can prove $\neg \neg \phi \rightarrow \phi$ in that system nevertheless.

Comment: Also I asked for that proof since there's this proof https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Double_Negation/Double_Negation_Elimination/Sequent_Form/Formulation_1 that uses LEM

Comment: @Pooria OK, so you're asking for a proof of $\neg \neg \phi \rightarrow \phi$ that does not use LEM and/or $\bot \rightarrow \phi$  as one of its rules? Well, in the Hilbert system you use neither rule, and in some systems going from $\neg \neg \phi$ to $\phi$ is a rule, so you'd do it in 1 step there. I'll attach a pic of a proof done in Fitch, which is a proof system I use.

Comment: So after all I guess since I'm considering classical logic that's been a mistake searching for a proof for DNE, actually what made me confused was the paragraph starting with "What is classical Logic" on page 2 of this doc https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15317-f09/lectures/07-classical.pdf that made me think DNE may be not an axiom in classical logic.

Comment: @Pooria Hmm, I'm not versed in constructionist or intuitionist logics ... it's pure classical logic for me! :)

Comment: could you tell me your take on that paragraph in that doc?

Comment: @Pooria The author seems to be showing that using LEM as a rule you can derive DNE, and vice versa.... which of course does not mean that you *have* to use the one to prove the other, as my Answer shows.

Comment: Hmmm... some guy told me in some system of classical logic, you may have for example law of the excluded middle as an axiom from which you have to derive DNE and that paragraph means that, what a lol!

Comment: @Pooria ... 'you have to derive DNE' ... in order to do what?

Comment: To prove all things that need double negation elimination in their proofs I guess!

Comment: @Pooria :) Sure!   But that still doesn't mean you *have to* use LEM.. it's just that you *can* use it (assuming you have it, of course ... e.g. both Fitch and the Hilbert system do not have LEM as a rule ... though of course both can derive LEM from the rules they do have) .. did I mention that it's all relative to whatever rules you have and do not have? :)

Comment: Also I just meant not using $\bot\vdash\varphi$ as you can see in the title ^^

Answer (score 2):

If we look at this from the perspective of something like intuitionistic natural deduction, I don't believe so.

First, recall that we can take negation to be non-primitive, i.e. ($\neg P := P \rightarrow \bot$).  Recall also that $\bot$ has no intro rules and a single elimination rule which corresponds to $\bot \vdash \varphi$.  Thus, if we remove this rule, we're basically treating $\bot$ like an arbitrary formula.  It seems to me then that a proof of LEM implying DNE should hold if we sub out $\bot$ for some arbitrary $Q$.  Doing this to LEM yields to scheme $P \vee (P \rightarrow Q)$, and DNE yields $((P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow P$.  Notice that the first is a classical tautology and the second is not even valid classically.  Since we then can't prove this implication classically, we certainly won't be able to do it intuitionistically.